# How to restart coundown timer for 24 hrs after expired in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm working on countdown timer where the time runs for daily 24 hrs. So far it was working great but when the times reaches zero, **I want it to restart the timer for another 24 hrs**.

When the user submits payment, what I do is save the deposit time in unix timestamp and use it to run the countdown for 24 hrs and give him 1% daily, but I can't able to run it daily.

What I've done so far:

```
    var deposit_time = user.deposit_time;
    var countDownDate = new Date(deposit_time * 1000).getTime() + 86400000;
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *
            60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        new Date(Date.now() + (3600 * 1000 * 24))


        document.getElementById("next_income_countdown").innerHTML =
            hours + "h " +
            minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("next_income_countdown").innerHTML = '00:00:00';
            // run for another 24 hrs
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Is the user supposed to keep their PC and browser up and running 24/7?

Comment: Nope, countdown intend to work even after when the Pc or browser is off

Comment: Well, if the PC is off, nothing is running on the client side. So what do you imagine should happen when they don't even turn it on within 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another's day worth of ms, `86400000`, to `countDownDate` when you reach zero `distance` to "reset" it:

```js
var deposit_time = user.deposit_time;
var countDownDate = new Date(deposit_time * 1000).getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();

// adjust countDownDate if there have been multiple days since deposit
while (now >= countDownDate) {
    countDownDate += 86400000;
}

var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("next_income_countdown").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance =< 0) {
        document.getElementById("next_income_countdown").innerHTML = '00:00:00';
        // run for another 24 hrs
        countDownDate += 86400000;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, Now you've increase time to another 24 hrs.. I guess, what would happen if the page refresh?? it takes deposit time again and re-run this code  `var deposit_time = user.deposit_time;
var countDownDate = new Date(deposit_time * 1000).getTime() + 86400000;
`

Comment: Answer updated. It now accounts for page refreshes and there being multiple days since the deposit.

Comment: doesn't the time or countDownDate variable reset  when the page refreshes ?

Comment: The countDownDate variable not "reset" on page refreshes because it's calculated from the user.deposit_time variable which persists between page refreshes.